# Get COM Port (Gertec)

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

I need to locate "COM Port" of Gertec Device.
I tried some things that are just below, I used several other things too and I didn't succeed.

Using this instruction it returns me Gertec but it does not show "COM Port".

```
gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | Out-GridView -Title 'Select a device' -OutputMode Single | select name,description, deviceID, manufacturer, caption
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUWP9.png]

I run this instruction and it returns everything but the COM10 port
`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_SerialPort | Select-Object Name, Description, DeviceID, Manufacturer, Caption`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol0Am.png]

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Powershell List Serial Ports + description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24307507/powershell-list-serial-ports-description)
has this advice.

To list all serial devices :

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort
```

There is also a nice
[script by not2qubit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76259155/165358)
that I reproduce here:

```
$mydevs = (Get-PnPDevice | Where-Object{$_.PNPClass -in  "WPD","AndroidUsbDeviceClass","Modem","Ports" } | 
    Where-Object{$_.Present -in "True"} | 
    Select-Object Name,Description,Manufacturer,PNPClass,Service,Present,Status,DeviceID | 
    Sort-Object Name)


$mydevs | Format-Table Description, Manufacturer, PNPClass, Service,
    @{Label="COM port"; Expression={ ($_.Name -Match "\((COM\d{1,2})\)" | Out-Null && $Matches[1]) }},
    @{Label="VID:PID"; Expression={ ($_.DeviceID -Match "USB\\VID_([0-9a-fA-F]{4})\&PID_([0-9a-fA-F]{4})" | Out-Null && ('{0}{1}{2}' -f ${Matches}[1], ":", ${Matches}[2]).ToLower() ) }},
    Present, Status
```

You might need to add more types for the `PNPClass` inside the
first command above to also include the Gertec Device.
See the linked answer for an example of the output.

Answer (score 0):

You could obtain the relevent info from registry

```
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM\"
```

pipe the result to filter for your Gertec Device but not sure what the specfic filter needs to be maybe in your case something like.

```
| Select-Object "*ger*"
```